# Password protecting web page

Tags: security, web, passwords

I want to password protect a web page. I'm wondering if anyone would critique my approach.

An anonymous user would go to the page and a modal would open up asking the user to enter a password. I would of course not display any content at the back in case anyone decides to be clever and display:none; the modal.

Once the user enters the password, I would redirect and save a randomly generated token as a cookie and check for that so that user wouldn't have to keep entering the password.

Just wondering if there are any security issues here aside from a personal physically accessing the computer and also if there would be any improvements that could be made.

I know I'm still being a little vague on some details, so let me know if there's anything important that I left out in regards to exact implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Even though what you describe might work, in general it's a bad idea to implement your own security. Even if you use https to prevent sniffing of the token, someone might find that your random numbers are not really random and be able to guess the next number.

You will be better off using one of the security feature that comes with the framework in which you are building your application. Most frameworks support something like forms-based authentication. It might even support claims-based authN with security tokens.

As you're not mentioning what framework you're using, I can't recommend anything.

Comment: I actually have an entire user authentication system in place. I wanted to allow users to create a page that would be password-protected.

Comment: That was not clear from the original question. Are you trying to allow the user to create web pages like in a wiki? I'm not familiar with Golang.

Comment: The idea is conceptually the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's a horrible idea.  The password as a cookie would be transmitted in the clear in every HTTP request.  There are plenty of examples of how to do this correctly.  I am not going to elaborate because this question is very likely going to be flagged.   NEVER save a password anywhere.  The first thing to do with a submitted password is compute a hash value.  The hash becomes the password.

Comment: Not the password as a cookie, I would save a token as a cookie.

Comment: A randomly generated token of sufficient length that would be stored in a db/redis.

Comment: I must start with, "There's no such thing as a secure system, just degrees of insecurity.". Your approach would work, you are implementing something similar to a session token? I imagine you would be putting an expiration date on the session (stored server side) and linking the session to the user's IP. That way, if I stole the token, I would have to spoof the user's IP to use it.

Comment: password or token neither should be a cookie.  A session variable would be better.  The token is passed in the clear.  I could sniff the packet and then make an HTTP request with the token and have the same access as the legitimate user.

Comment: using secret cookies and https